# Basic d3 not outputting circles until I refresh the screen

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some seemingly basic d3 javascript code.  When I run it, nothing gets displayed.  The transfer from the server seems to freeze after it has run some of the js i.e. when I step through it runs the first attribute (cx) and then seems to halt there.  In the Inspector, the  tag is displayed, but the circle is not.  The weird thing is that the circle(s) get displayed for a number of milliseconds before it runs the code again.

N.B. I have removed the data and replaced it with numbers to simplify it.

It only does this in Firefox, not in Chrome.

```js
var rows = [[10, 20], [30, 40]];

var h = 200;
var w = 500;

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(rows)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return 20;
   })
   .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return 20;
   })
   .attr("r", 5);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="./scatter1.js"></script> -->
```

Comment: ever tried removing the `defer` attribute? ever tried comparing the console output? (F12). have no Firefox installed, but these would both be possible approaches to understand the issue better.

Comment: Yeah.  Tried both to no avail.  Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: is the console output the same? maybe add further logging, to have more events logged.

Comment: I'll give it a try.  Thanks.